# How to perform a 'join' with a sub element in XQuery

Tags: xquery

Im not sure how to word what I am trying to do, but I am trying to get all touples of FID, BID, and Something.  Consider the following XML:

```
<FOO>
    <FID>f1</FID>
    <NAME>f1</NAME>
    <BAR>
        <BID>b1</BID>
        <SOMETHING>15</SOMETHING>
    </BAR>
    <BAR>
        <BID>b2</BID>
        <SOMETHING>25</SOMETHING>
    </BAR>
</FOO>
<FOO>
    <FID>f2</FID>
    <NAME>f2</NAME>
    <BAR>
        <BID>b1</BID>
        <SOMETHING>35</SOMETHING>
    </BAR>
    <BAR>
        <BID>b3</BID>
        <SOMETHING>0</SOMETHING>
    </BAR>
</FOO>
```

What I need is:

```
b1  f1  15
b1  f2  35
b2  f1  25
b3  f2  0
```

Anyone know the syntax that I would use?
I tried:

```
for $foo in /root/FOO
for $bar in /root/FOO/BAR
let $fid := $foo/FID/text() where $foo/BAR/BID/text()=$bar/BID/text()
let $bid := $foo/BAR/BID/text() where $foo/BAR/BID/text()=$bar/BID/text()
let $something := $foo/BAR/SOMETHING/text() where $foo/BAR/BID/text()=$bar/BID/text()
```

Comment: What did you try? Stack Overflow is not a freelancers-for-free-platform. Also, your XML input is not well-formed.

Comment: fixed the xml, I tried a double loop over Foo and Bar, but that produces duplicates

Comment: Looks better now. For a good question, also include the actual output (and any error messages and warnings you see). Have a look at [ask] and [how to create an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) for more details.

Comment: And please make sure to post code without syntax errors. If you need help with getting the syntax right, try to create a minimal example first and ask for help with the syntax before getting to _what_ the code should do. I removed the downvote, but your question is still far away from an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd wanted to order by the `<FID/>` elements first, it'd be as easy as looping over the `<FOO/>`s, for each of them over its `<BAR/>`s and dumping a string each time:

```
for $foo in /root/FOO
for $bar in /BAR
return string-join(($foo/FID, $bar/BID, $bar/SOMETHING), ' ')
```

For grouping by `<BID/>`s, you have to loop over those first and collect the other information relatively:

```
for $bar in //BAR
order by $bar/BID
return string-join(($bar/BID, $bar/../FID, $bar/SOMETHING), ' ')
```

A small remark (as I wasn't able to run your code without major cleanup): `$foo` and `$FOO` are not the same, XQuery is case sensitive. Furthermore, you're missing a `return` clause.